# How to go about creating this clippath design with a background?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, scrollview, flutter-clippath

How would I go about making this design in a ScrollView?

[image]

I was thinking about making two containers one with the yellow color & second with the white color and then using clipPath to morph the edges of the white container. But, the problem I would face is that the background image would leave space below the left edge of yellow container which would seem odd so, I would have to absolute position the white container on the Y axis and this entirely would be in a ScrollView which seemed kind of hard to achieve. So, what would be the best suited method to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Stack to stack the background image and the column which contains the top textfield and the bottom white container. Then you clip the bottom container

Code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(4, 20, 31, 1),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            filled: true,
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            )
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ClipPath(
                          clipper: MyClipper(radius: 50),
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path>{

  final double radius;
  MyClipper({required this.radius});
  
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
    ..lineTo(0, 2*radius)
    ..arcTo(
      Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(radius, 2*radius), radius: radius), 
      math.pi, 
      math.pi/2, 
      false
    )
    ..lineTo(radius, radius)
    ..lineTo(size.width-radius, radius)
    ..arcTo(
      Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width-radius, 0), radius: radius), 
      math.pi/2, 
      -math.pi/2, 
      false
    )
    ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
    ..lineTo(0, size.height)
    ..close()
    ;
  }
  
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(MyClipper oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: How would all of this including the yellow container go in a ScrollView?

Comment: Put the Stack inside a SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: Do you want the elements to scroll inside the white container? Or should the white container scroll up with the elements together?